# App folder is not uploading into bitbucket when integrated with Angular-CLI in angular5

Tags: angular, git, bitbucket, angular-cli, angular5

I am new to Angular-CLI and Angular5.

In my main repository, I had

1. .gitignore
2. _fmr-metadata.json
3. _source-code-classification.md
4. readme.md.

I have cloned the above pointed to my branch.

I had created Angular-CLI project, updated app folder with my additional components and merged the cli project files into my main repository by copying the files.

Now my local project is pointing to my branch with cli file and basic files(above 4).

When I push the code, All the files are pushed successfully.Except the app folder. App folder is displaying as a folder, when I click on the app folder, its showing "Subproject commit 12dcexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".

How can I get my app folder, similar to normal files in my commit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your .gitignore file, you might have the app folder included in gitignore, hence git ignores your changes in that folder.

Comment: Thank you @PM. I found out the issue, it is because I didn't remove the cache thorugh git.